# std::accumulate alternative for the C programming language

Tags: c, macros

I've come up with some simple implementation for algorithms in `C` and more specifically for `std::accumulate` alternate since I need something like it recently. Can you provide some review on the approach?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define ARRSIZE(X) (sizeof(X) / sizeof(X[0]))


#define ACCUMULATE(RET, FIRST, LAST, INIT, SUM_CB)      \
    do {                                                \
        RET = INIT;                                     \
        while (FIRST != LAST){                          \
            RET = SUM_CB(RET, *FIRST);                  \
            FIRST++;                                    \
        }                                               \
    } while(0);

/**
 * example usage
 * sum integers and sum strings by some delimiter
*/
struct str_t
{
    char data[512];
};



struct str_t sumStr(struct str_t a, struct str_t b)
{
    struct str_t ret = {0};
    strcat(ret.data, a.data);
    strcat(ret.data, "--");
    strcat(ret.data, b.data);
    return ret;
}


struct A { int a, b, c; };

struct A sumA(struct A a, struct A b) {
    struct A ret ;
    ret.a = a.a + b.a;
    ret.b = a.b + b.b;
    ret.c = a.c + b.c;
    return ret;
}


int main()
{
    unsigned long i;

    struct A sumvec[10];
    struct str_t sumstr[10];
    memset(sumstr, 0, sizeof(sumstr));

    for(i=0; i < ARRSIZE(sumvec); i++) {
        sumvec[i].a = i;
        sumvec[i].b = i+1;
        sumvec[i].c = i+2;
        snprintf(sumstr[i].data, sizeof(sumstr[i].data), "%d", i);
    }

    for(i=0; i < ARRSIZE(sumvec); i++) {
        printf("[%d][%d][%d]\r\n", sumvec[i].a ,sumvec[i].b,sumvec[i].c);
    }


    struct A ret = {sumvec[0].a, sumvec[0].b, sumvec[0].c};
    struct A* pBegin = &sumvec[1];
    struct A* pEnd = &sumvec[ARRSIZE(sumvec)];

    ACCUMULATE(ret, pBegin, pEnd,  ret, sumA)

    printf("SUM: [%d][%d][%d]\r\n", ret.a, ret.b, ret.c);


    struct str_t retstr;
    strcat(retstr.data, sumstr[0].data);

    struct str_t *pBegs = &sumstr[1];
    struct str_t *pEnds = &sumstr[ARRSIZE(sumstr)];

    ACCUMULATE(retstr, pBegs, pEnds, retstr, sumStr);

    printf("SUM STR: [%s]\r\n", retstr.data);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When using the `do { ... } while (0)` idiom for macros, we don't generally include the terminating semicolon in the definition.  That's so we can use it like a function call:

```
if (condition)
    ACCUMULATE(result, a, b, 0, add);
else
    ACCUMULATE(result, a, c, 10, add);
```

There's a typo in the `ARRSIZE()` macro: where we protect X from misbinding - should be `(X)[0]`, not `(X[0])`:

```
#define ARRSIZE(X) (sizeof (X) / sizeof (X)[0])
```

Also, be careful with this macro when its argument isn't a whole, completely defined array.  In particular, it will be wrong when the argument is a variable-length (dynamically-allocated) array, or when the argument is a pointer (perhaps the array decayed to pointer - that can easily catch you out!).

In the sample usage:

- Identifiers ending in `_t` are reserved for future use by the standard library, so `str_t` should be renamed.
- It's a shame, after being so careful to use `snprintf()` avoid overflow, that we  we then use unchecked `strcat();strcat();strcat();` in `sumStr()`  - why not `snprintf()` there, too?
- A lot of needless parens around the arguments to `sizeof`.  Just write `sizeof sumstr` instead of `sizeof(sumstr)`, for example.

Comment: You may also want to mention that the `ARRSIZE` macro often [confuses people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/why-isnt-the-size-of-an-array-parameter-the-same-as-within-main) when it decays to a pointer and that it doesn't work with dynamically sized arrays.

Comment: Thanks @Edward - edited.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [@Toby Speight](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/253677/29485) fine answer.

> Can you provide some review on the approach?

I found the macro `ACCUMULATE()`, at best, slightly useful.  I did not see it adding clarity.  Perhaps it would be a useful benefit in a larger code usage.

A particular issue with `ACCUMULATE(a, b,c, d, e)` is the 9 usages of the 5 arguments - potentially incurring re-use problems.

At a minimum `ACCUMULATE()`, deserve some comments detailing its usage, simpler sample usage and limitations.  Do not assume C users are familiar with `std::accumulate` from another language.

---

I realize this is demonstrative code. Yet ...

**Bug**

Attempting to concatenate to an uninitialized string.  Use `strcpy()`.

```
struct str_t retstr;
// strcat(retstr.data, sumstr[0].data);
strcpy(retstr.data, sumstr[0].data);
```

**Walk a string once, not 3 times**

As `strlen(ret.data)` increases, `strcat(ret.data, ...` becomes increasingly expensive.

```
//strcat(ret.data, a.data);
//strcat(ret.data, "--");
//strcat(ret.data, b.data);
sprintf(ret.data, "%s--%s", a.data, b.data);
```

Robust would consider using `snprintf()`.

**Simplify initialization**

```
// struct str_t sumstr[10];
// memset(sumstr, 0, sizeof(sumstr));
struct str_t sumstr[10] = { 0 };

// struct A ret = {sumvec[0].a, sumvec[0].b, sumvec[0].c};
struct A ret = sumvec[0];
```

**`\r\n` vs. `\n`"**

`stdout` is normally in text mode and will translates `'\n'` into the end-of-line- encoding best for that system.  Recommend `'\n'`.

```
// printf("[%d][%d][%d]\r\n", sumvec[i].a ,sumvec[i].b,sumvec[i].c);
printf("[%d][%d][%d]\n", sumvec[i].a ,sumvec[i].b,sumvec[i].c);
```

**Minor: Unclear mixed use of types `unsigned long` and `int`**

```
struct A { int a, b, c; };

    unsigned long i;
    sumvec[i].a = i;
    sumvec[i].b = i+1;
    sumvec[i].c = i+2;
```

Why is `i` `unsigned long` and not `int` to match the s`struct` members or `size_t` to match the range for indexing?

Comment: Thanks. Good point but I didn’t focus on example usage just a demo of the macro, but will fix it.

Comment: Agh!  I had the `\r` in my mind, then forgot it again whilst writing my answer!  It always helps to have more than one of us reviewing...